# Emma does not recognize [ctl] command in Java7

Tags: code-coverage, instrumentation, emma, ctl

I am using the latest version of Emma i.e. 2.0.5312 and Java 7.
If I run the following command to get the coverage.ec on the fly, I get an error.
**java  emma ctl -connect localhost:47653 -command coverage.get,coverage.ec**

```
*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown command:
[ctl]
    at com.vladium.emma.Command.create(Command.java:51)
    at emma.main(emma.java:39)*
```

This error is usually seen if an older version of Emma is used but I believe build 5312 is the latest build of Emma. Also, this error is not seen in Java 6.

Has someone come across this issue and been able to resolve it? Any pointers will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The latest and last version of Emma is 2.1.5320. I downloaded this version and was able to overcome the above mentioned error.